# Conversion of Daily pandas dataframe to minute frequency

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe as defined below (df) with daily frequency and I would like to convert this to minute frequency, starting at 8:30 and ending at 16:00.

```
import pandas as pd
dict = [
        {'ticker':'jpm','date': '2016-11-28','returns': '0.2'},
{ 'ticker':'ge','date': '2016-11-28','returns': '0.2'},
{'ticker':'fb', 'date': '2016-11-28','returns': '0.2'},
{'ticker':'aapl', 'date': '2016-11-28','returns': '0.2'},
{'ticker':'msft','date': '2016-11-28','returns': '0.2'},
{'ticker':'amzn','date': '2016-11-28','returns': '0.2'},
{'ticker':'jpm','date': '2016-11-29','returns': '0.2'},
{'ticker':'ge', 'date': '2016-11-29','returns': '0.2'},
{'ticker':'fb','date': '2016-11-29','returns': '0.2'},
{'ticker':'aapl','date': '2016-11-29','returns': '0.2'},
{'ticker':'msft','date': '2016-11-29','returns': '0.2'},
{'ticker':'amzn','date': '2016-11-29','returns': '0.2'}
]
df = pd.DataFrame(dict)
df['date']      = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df=df.set_index(['date','ticker'], drop=True)
```

Can anyone suggest how to do this?

Comment: There is no variable for `df1`, is that a typo ?

Comment: Do you think `4:00` or `16:00` ?

Comment: sorry I fixed the df1 thing. Yes, I meant 16:00, sorry about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need reshape by [`DataFrame.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) for `DatetimeIndex`, then set minute frequency by [`DataFrame.asfreq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.asfreq.html), filter times by [`DataFrame.between_time`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.between_time.html) and last use [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) for `MultiIndex`:

```
df1 = df.unstack().asfreq('Min', method='ffill').between_time('8:30','16:00').stack()
print (df1.head(10))

                           returns
date                ticker        
2016-11-28 08:30:00 aapl       0.2
                    amzn       0.2
                    fb         0.2
                    ge         0.2
                    jpm        0.2
                    msft       0.2
2016-11-28 08:31:00 aapl       0.2
                    amzn       0.2
                    fb         0.2
                    ge         0.2
```

Comment: don't forget to green tick @Tartaglia :) nice answer Jezarael!

Comment: @Datanovice - Thank you :)

Comment: Jezrael, the approach above does not work for 2 row dataframes for some strange reason, I have posted this in a new thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56895049/conversion-of-daily-pandas-dataframe-to-minute-frequency-does-not-work-for-2-row

Comment: Jezrael, the above approach causes another problem of incorrectly forward filling missing rows, I have posted this in a new thread as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56926406/conversion-of-daily-pandas-dataframe-to-minute-frequency-incorrectly-fills-dates