# Conversion of Daily pandas dataframe to minute frequency does not work for 2 row dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, frequency

I am trying to convert a daily frequency dataframe to minute data, and in a previous post it was suggested to use the ffil method below but it does not seem to work with dataframes that consist of only 2 rows ([Conversion of Daily pandas dataframe to minute frequency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56371996/conversion-of-daily-pandas-dataframe-to-minute-frequency)).

So the below dataframe is supposed to be converted.

```
import pandas as pd
dict = [
        {'ticker':'jpm','date': '2016-11-28','returns': 0.2},
{ 'ticker':'ge','date': '2016-11-28','returns': 0.2},
{'ticker':'fb', 'date': '2016-11-28','returns': 0.2},
{'ticker':'aapl', 'date': '2016-11-28','returns': 0.2},
{'ticker':'msft','date': '2016-11-28','returns': 0.2},
{'ticker':'amzn','date': '2016-11-28','returns': 0.2},
{'ticker':'jpm','date': '2016-11-29','returns': 0.2},
{'ticker':'ge', 'date': '2016-11-29','returns': 0.2},
{'ticker':'fb','date': '2016-11-29','returns': 0.2},
{'ticker':'aapl','date': '2016-11-29','returns': 0.2},
{'ticker':'msft','date': '2016-11-29','returns': 0.2},
{'ticker':'amzn','date': '2016-11-29','returns': 0.2}
]
df = pd.DataFrame(dict)
df['date']      = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df=df.set_index(['date','ticker'], drop=True)
```

This works on the entire dataframe:

```
df_min = df.unstack().asfreq('Min', method='ffill').between_time('8:30','16:00').stack()
```

But when I work with a smaller dataframe it returns an empty dataframe for some reason:

```
df2=df.iloc[0:2,:]

df2_min = df2.unstack().asfreq('Min', method='ffill').between_time('8:30','16:00').stack()
```

Does anyone have an explanation for this odd behaviour?

edt: I noticed the code only works if the dataframe has at least 7 rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have only 2 row input DataFrame then after reshape by `unstack` get one row `DataFrame` and pandas cannot create continous minute `DataFrame`, because only one value of `DatetimeIndex`.

Possible solution is add next day after reshape, fill it last previous row data, apply solution and in last steps remove last helper row by positions with `iloc`:

```
df2=df.iloc[0:2]
print (df2)
                   returns
date       ticker         
2016-11-28 jpm         0.2
           ge          0.2

df3 = df2.unstack()
print (df3)
ticker         jpm   ge
date                   
2016-11-28     0.2  0.2
df3.loc[df3.index.max() + pd.Timedelta(1, unit='d')] = df3.iloc[-1]
print (df3)
           returns     
ticker         jpm   ge
date                   
2016-11-28     0.2  0.2
2016-11-29     0.2  0.2 <- helper row

df_min = df3.asfreq('Min', method='ffill')
print (df_min.tail())
                    returns     
ticker                  jpm   ge
date                            
2016-11-28 23:56:00     0.2  0.2
2016-11-28 23:57:00     0.2  0.2
2016-11-28 23:58:00     0.2  0.2
2016-11-28 23:59:00     0.2  0.2
2016-11-29 00:00:00     0.2  0.2 <- helper row

df_min = df_min.iloc[:-1].between_time('8:30','16:00').stack()
#print (df_min)
```