# Conversion of Daily pandas dataframe to minute frequency incorrectly fills dates

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to convert a daily frequency dataframe to minute data, that is for each row, I want to have that combination of ticker and date repeated on minute basis, and in a previous post ([Conversion of Daily pandas dataframe to minute frequency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56371996/conversion-of-daily-pandas-dataframe-to-minute-frequency)) it was suggested to me to use the ffil method below but this approach incorrectly forward fills individual rows for certain tickers to the next day. This is illustrated below:

So the below dataframe is supposed to be converted and it works because the dates are consecutively:

```
import pandas as pd
dict1 = [
        {'ticker':'jpm','date': '2016-11-27','returns': 0.2},
{'ticker':'ge','date': '2016-11-28','returns': 0.2},
{'ticker':'amzn','date': '2016-11-29','returns': 0.2}
]
df1= pd.DataFrame(dict1)
df1['date']      = pd.to_datetime(df1['date'])
df1=df1.set_index(['date','ticker'], drop=True)  

df_min1 = df1.unstack().asfreq('Min', method='ffill').between_time('13:30','13:32').stack()
```

Below df2 skips 1 day, and then in the outcome dataframe df_min2, the first ticker gets repeated in the originally skipped date:

```
dict2 = [
        {'ticker':'jpm','date': '2016-11-27','returns': 0.2},
{'ticker':'ge','date': '2016-11-29','returns': 0.2},
{'ticker':'amzn','date': '2016-11-30','returns': 0.2}
]
df2 = pd.DataFrame(dict2)
df2['date']      = pd.to_datetime(df2['date'])
df2=df2.set_index(['date','ticker'], drop=True)  

df_min2 = df2.unstack().asfreq('Min', method='ffill').between_time('13:30','13:32').stack()
```

Can anyone suggest a solution?

Comment: hmmm, pandas with timeseries working best if consecutive datetimeindex. So finally need remove rows with `2016-11-28`, because not exist in `date` ?

Comment: Yes, my datetimeindex is not consecutive. So every day, I have a different list of tickers for that day, the next day, I have different tickers. Sometimes, a day is skipped.

Comment: I know for a fact, that any ticker will appears only 4 times a year at most. So if a ticker appears on 2 consecutive days, only the first one is correct. So maybe one could loop through the index to see if there are any consecutive tickers, and if there are any, only keep the first one.

Comment: I figured out a solution, I simply create new column at the very beginning with the daily dates, and another column at the end with daily dates, if both do not match, I drop the row. I will post the solution for future reference.

Comment: I highly appreciate your help with this and also with the other problems before jezrael, thanks!!!!

Answer (score 1):

So the solution below works for me, I simply create new column with the daily dates and after the conversion, I creaete a another daily column and only keep the rows where both match:

```
  df['date_column']=pd.to_datetime(df.index.get_level_values(0))
  df['date_column']=pd.to_datetime(df['date_column']).dt.date

...converting dataframe...


  df['date_column2']=pd.to_datetime(df.index.get_level_values(0))
  df['date_column2']=pd.to_datetime(df['date_column2']).dt.date
  df=df[df['date_column']==df['date_column2']]
```